# How to start graphite via gunicorn?

Tags: nginx, graphite

I set up graphite with nginx and gunicorn. As soon as I start I get this output:

```
server:/opt/graphite/webapp/graphite # gunicorn graphite_wsgi:application
[2019-07-10 16:24:30 +0000] [13244] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
[2019-07-10 16:24:30 +0000] [13244] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (13244)
[2019-07-10 16:24:30 +0000] [13244] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2019-07-10 16:24:30 +0000] [13248] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 13248
Could not import graphite.local_settings, using defaults!
[2019-07-10 14:24:30 +0000] [13248] [ERROR] Error handling request /tags/tagMultiSeries
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 135, in handle
    self.handle_request(listener, req, client, addr)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 176, in handle_request
    respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 157, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in get_response
    response = self._middleware_chain(request)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 43, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 93, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 135, in handle_uncaught_exception
    extra={'status_code': 500, 'request': request},
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1193, in error
    self._log(ERROR, msg, args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1286, in _log
    self.handle(record)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1296, in handle
    self.callHandlers(record)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1336, in callHandlers
    hdlr.handle(record)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 759, in handle
    self.emit(record)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/log.py", line 119, in emit
    message = "%s\n\n%s" % (self.format(no_exc_record), reporter.get_traceback_text())
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 334, in get_traceback_text
    return t.render(c)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 207, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 199, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 216, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1040, in render
    output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 736, in resolve
    new_obj = func(obj, *arg_vals)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaultfilters.py", line 255, in stringformat
    return ("%" + six.text_type(arg)) % value
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 79, in __repr__
    return repr(self.__cast())
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 131, in __cast
    return self.__text_cast()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 119, in __text_cast
    return func(*self.__args, **self.__kw)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 91, in reverse
    return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 440, in _reverse_with_prefix
    possibilities = self.reverse_dict.getlist(lookup_view)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 337, in reverse_dict
    return self._reverse_dict[language_code]
KeyError: 'en-us'
[2019-07-10 14:24:31 +0000] [13248] [ERROR] Error handling request /tags/tagMultiSeries
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 135, in handle
    self.handle_request(listener, req, client, addr)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 176, in handle_request
    respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 157, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in get_response
    response = self._middleware_chain(request)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 43, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 93, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 135, in handle_uncaught_exception
    extra={'status_code': 500, 'request': request},
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1193, in error
    self._log(ERROR, msg, args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1286, in _log
    self.handle(record)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1296, in handle
    self.callHandlers(record)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1336, in callHandlers
    hdlr.handle(record)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 759, in handle
    self.emit(record)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/log.py", line 119, in emit
    message = "%s\n\n%s" % (self.format(no_exc_record), reporter.get_traceback_text())
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 334, in get_traceback_text
    return t.render(c)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 207, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 199, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 216, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1040, in render
    output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 736, in resolve
    new_obj = func(obj, *arg_vals)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaultfilters.py", line 255, in stringformat
    return ("%" + six.text_type(arg)) % value
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 79, in __repr__
    return repr(self.__cast())
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 131, in __cast
    return self.__text_cast()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 119, in __text_cast
    return func(*self.__args, **self.__kw)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 91, in reverse
    return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 440, in _reverse_with_prefix
    possibilities = self.reverse_dict.getlist(lookup_view)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 337, in reverse_dict
    return self._reverse_dict[language_code]
KeyError: 'en-us'
^C[2019-07-10 16:24:32 +0000] [13244] [INFO] Handling signal: int
[2019-07-10 14:24:32 +0000] [13248] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 13248)
[2019-07-10 16:24:32 +0000] [13244] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
```

If I try to access nginx I get an Internal Server Error.

Unfortunaly I have no clue what this error is about

My /opt/graphite/webapp/graphite/graphite_wsgi.py looks like this:

```
import sys
# In case of multi-instance graphite, uncomment and set appropriate name
# import os
# os.environ['GRAPHITE_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'graphite.local_settings'
sys.path.append('/opt/graphite/webapp')

from graphite.wsgi import application
```

Does anyone have a hint for me what's wrong ? I have already tried with apache, but I get similar errors there, too. So I think there's something wrong in my graphite_wsgi.py - but that's just a guess

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Looks like some issue with Django, which version of Django and which version of Graphite are you using?

Comment: Hi Popielunch,

I am using the following versions at the moment :

Django: 1.11.22
Graphite-Web: 1.1.15
Python: 2.7.13

In the meantime I found some hint, that this error can be fixed my installing the module "requests" ( https://github.com/graphite-project/graphite-web/issues/1971 ), but this module is installed in my case :

requests         2.22.0

So it looks like this is not the reason ...